# Keep Partial Digits(S4,K2), all Alphabets and Full stops But remove all others digits (simple and those have decimal point)

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to keep partial digits but remove full digits from a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String testString = "I walked 2 miles in 4 hour. I went to K2. I have 2000 Rupes only. This is 2.4.";
        testString = testString.replaceAll("[0.0-9.9]", "");
        System.out.println(testString);
}
```

This is giving me following results.
"I walked  miles in  hour I went to K I have  Rupes only This is"
But I want to keep partial digits (like K2). Just want to remove full digits(2, 4 etc). Also I want to keep full stops but want to remove decimal points digits(2.4 etc).
I want these results.
"I walked  miles in  hour. I went to K2. I have  Rupes only. This is ."
 What should be correct regular expression?
I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])\d+(\.\d+)?(?![a-zA-Z])
```

for Java: `(?<![a-zA-Z])\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?![a-zA-Z])`

where:

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])` - negative lookbehind, search for letters
- `\d+(\.\d+)?` - numbers
- `(?![a-zA-Z])` - negitive lookahead, search for letters

negative lookarouds check if there is no letter directly before of efter number, before it replace substring

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lE2gX9/1)